# How to modify behavior of a class depending on its top parent?

Tags: css, less

I have a .tintTile that depends on parent, hence the & sas follows:

```
// Tint titles
.tintTitle {
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-family: @fontDemiBold;
    color: @colorOrangeKWS;

    .Windows7 & {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: @colorOrangeKWS;
    }
}
```

In many others classes, I use the .tintTitle as follows:

```
// titles, orange bold
.tab {
    &>div {
        .tintTitle;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't achieve the .Windows7 (provided the fact Windows7 is a class set to the body tag as follows:

```
<body class="Windows7">

        <p class="tintTitle">Good, it works</p>

        <div class="tab">
            <div>This title doesn't make it</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal with less beside duplicating every .tintTitle where it's required?

Comment: Could you please add a sample selector (or) expected CSS output to the question mate? I am a bit confused on what exactly is needed. Are you looking for some way to come up with `.Windows7 .tab > div`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question your code should work in Less, see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwNWmq

Less code:

```
// Tint titles
.tintTitle {
    text-transform: uppercase; 

    color: green;

    .Windows7 & {
      text-transform: initial; 
      color: red;
    }
}
.tab {
    &>div {
        .tintTitle;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Your are using the [parent selectors feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) of Less to [change the selector order](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order)

The only thing you should notice will be that properties set for your (not having `.windows`) will be also applied for your `.windows` selectors. That's why i have to set `text-transform: initial;`, otherwise the `.windows *` also get uppercased cause the also match .tintTitle.